# Make sure Ubuntu is connected to right wifi or reconnect to right wifi using a script

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, scripts, internet

Sometimes Ubuntu loses its connection (for example the router goes down), and I want to make sure that it reconnects to the right network. I don't want to just check that there is an internet connection because the modem might be down. I would use this in a script called by `cron`.

In pseudo code:

```
if not connected to "wifiname" then 
  connect to "wifiname".
```

It should be simple, but most solutions want to check if connected to the Internet, but not a certain network.

Comment: Why not simply delete the known connections in Network Manager and leave only the one you want ? It connects only to whats remembered like on android. I dont see a point for a script. Can you explain ?

Comment: It's hard to explain but I have 3 wifi networks and sometimes want to stay connected to a certain one. For example I have a VPN service connected to one. Another gives better speed for some reason. Even when the VPN is off. I want to apologize to the mods who had to edit my post. I was on my phone and in a rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the name of your configured connection with:

```
$ ls /etc/NetWorkManager/system-connections/
```

Replace the `My Choice Network` with the name of the network you want to connect to.

Run the script.  If it's connected to that network, it'll do nothing.  If it's not connected to that network it connect to it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

wifiname="My Choice Network"
connectedname="$(nmcli -f active,ssid dev wifi|egrep "yes"|awk '{$1="";print}'|sed "s/^[ \t]*//")"

echo "Connedted: [$connectedname]"
echo "wifiname:  [$wifiname]"

if [[ ! "$connectedname" == "$wifiname" ]]; then
        nmcli connection up id "$wifiname"
fi
```